# Visual Studio Code mac finder text preview not working for json or css

Tags: css, json, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm on MacOS Mojave and I recently updated .json and .css files to open in Visual Studio Code. Now I can't preview their text contents inside of finder while in column view. Has anyone else come across this?

Attached is an example of a [markdown file that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5xRq.png) and a [.json file that doesn't show its contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1wzR.png).

Comment: Have you looked at the search filters on the excluded files to see if json or css aren't there?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm not familiar with search filters. I just searched for it but didn't find any good information on them. If you know of a good post or thread on search filters could you share that link? Thanks @Machado !

Comment: Try reading this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files